# How to keep voltage at 0 or high resistance during circuit warm-up?

Tags: timer, timing

This is a timing question. I have this motion-detector: http://www.mpja.com/download/31227sc.pdf

It says "Sensor module is powered up after a minute, in this initialization time intervals during this module will output 0-3 times, a minute later enters the standby state"

I want to connect the output to an alarm. But I don't want the alarm beeping 3 times during the initialization/warm-up. So for the first minute, I basically want no current going through the alarm, but after the first minute, it should be effectively directly connected to the motion-detector. What components would allow me to do this?

Comment: You can try to set a 60s RC delay on the inhibit pin in place or parrellel to the CDS. Really best bet is to follow this with module with gating logic.

Comment: What voltage are you using for the module? They say anything from about 5-20 V can be used. Also, it appears the output is 3.3 V TTL. Have you actually measured the output voltage on the module? If so, what is the value? What if you load the output with, say \$1\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ or \$10\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$? What then? What does your alarm require as its input?

Comment: Yes the output seems to be about 3V. The alarm responds to 3-24V input: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B008OTOQX6/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

@sstobbe what is "the inhibit pin" and CDS?

Comment: @bhh1988 CDs is the photo cell, its pin9 on the bisxxx control chip

Answer (score 1):

You got everything wrong. The HC-SR501 PIR motion detector is designed to interface with a low-power **logic input** of Arduino-type platform. The "an alarm" that you have is just a buzzer. It doesn't just "respond" to 3-24V input, it needs a solid power to buzz. The motion-detector can't possibly supply 30 mA of current to this primitive buzzer, its output is weakened with 1 k series resistor...

So you need to re-think your entire project. You need to include an Arduino MCU, to control a transistor switch, which will drive the buzzer. And program the Arduino to ignore the PIR input for first minutes after power-on if you don't want to hear false alarms.